# Linux Distributed Lock Manager

Tags: linux, locking, distributed

I have a program kept on two nodes. I want to make sure when one node is running the program the other should not. To achieve this i'm planning to use linux distributed lock manager (DLM). My questions are -

1) Which DLM to use? OCFS2 or GFS?

2) Is there any cluster configuration needs to be done before implementing DLM?

3) Do i need to install Red Hat cluster suite software for DLM to work?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to install red hat cluster suite. The DLM libraries needed will be installed along with the packages. GFS is a clustered file system that maintains locks and allows data to be accessed by multiple nodes at the same time and is recommended for use with RCS as the shared data store.

Below are the packages needed.

```
yum install rgmanager lvm2-cluster gfs2-utils;
```

You might find my series of articles on creating a cluster with red hat at [http://bigthinkingapplied.com/creating-a-ha-cluster-with-red-hat-cluster-suite](http://bigthinkingapplied.com/creating-a-ha-cluster-with-red-hat-cluster-suite/) helpful.